# Component getting re rendered multiple times in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

Since I am pretty new to react hooks, I am unable to understand some part of the existing code why my component is re-rendering multiple times when the state of an attribute gets changed. Below is the component code. I have added console.log for better understanding.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import api from '../api/api';
import { UPLOAD_DATA } from '../api/urls';
import Alert from '../layout/alerts/Alerts';



const StudentDetailsView = ({ symbol }) => {
    console.log("inside StudentDetailsView");
    const initialState = {
        form: {
            qualification: symbol.qualification,
            profession: symbol.profession
        }
    };

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(null);
    const [editFlag, setEditFlag] = useState(false);
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initialState);
    console.log("before dataUpdated");
    const [dataUpdated, setDataUpdated] =useState(false);
    console.log("after dataUpdated");
    const formRef = useRef(null);

    const handleCancel = () => {
        setEditFlag(false);
        setInputs(initialState);
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log("inside handleSumbit");
        const form = formRef.current;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        form.classList.add('was-validated');

        if (form.checkValidity()) {
            callback();
        }
        
    };

    const callback = ()=> {
        setLoading(true);
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('model', new Blob([JSON.stringify(inputs.form)], {
            type: 'application/json'
        }));

        api.multipartEdit(UPLOAD_DATA, formData)
            .then(response => {
                setInputs(inputs => ({
                    ...inputs,
                    form: {
                        qualification: response.data.qualification,
                        profession: response.data.profession
                    }
                }));
                setErrors(null);
                setDataUpdated(true);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setErrors(error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
                setEditFlag(false);
            });
    }

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        event.persist();
        setInputs(inputs => ({
            ...inputs,
            form: {
                ...inputs.form,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            }
        }));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                errors &&
                <Alert type={errors.type} title={errors.title} description={errors.description} id="alert" />
            }

            <div >
                {editFlag ? (
                    <div >
                    </div>
                ) :
                    (<div className="edit">
                        <button type="button" onClick={() => setEditFlag(!editFlag)}>
                            Edit
                        </button>
                    </div>)
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                <form className="needs-validation" onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef} noValidate>
                    {
                        editFlag ? (<div className="update-cancel-button">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >
                                {loading ? (
                                    <div className="spinner-border uxf-spinner-border-sm">
                                        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                                    </div>) : 'Update'}
                            </button>
                            <button className="btn btn-secondary cancel-button" type="button" onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
                        </div>) : <div></div>
                    }
                    <dl className="uxf-dl uxf-dl-horizontal">
                        <dt>Name</dt>
                        <dd>{symbol.name}</dd>
                        
                        <dt>Age</dt>
                        <dd>{symbol.age}</dd>

                        <dt>Qualification</dt>
                        {editFlag ?
                            (<dd>
                                <textarea className="form-control" name="qualification" id="qualification"
                                    value={inputs.form.qualification}
                                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    maxLength="255"></textarea>
                                <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                    Please provide a Qualification.
                                </div>
                            </dd>)
                            :
                            (<dd>{dataUpdated ? (inputs.form.qualification ? inputs.form.qualification : '-') : (symbol.qualification ? symbol.qualification : '-')}</dd>)
                        }
                        <dt>Profession</dt>
                        {editFlag ?
                            (<dd>
                                <textarea className="form-control" name="profession" id="profession"
                                    value={inputs.form.profession}
                                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                                    minLength="1"
                                    maxLength="1000"
                                    required></textarea>
                                <div className="invalid-feedback">
                                    Please provide a Profession.
                                </div>
                            </dd>)
                            :
                            (<dd>{dataUpdated ? inputs.form.profession : symbol.profession}</dd>)
                        }
                    </dl>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default StudentDetailsView;
```

Since my component is getting re-rendered, my state values which are getting set in the code ***(eg, dataUpdated)*** are getting updated with the default value again and again. How do I prevent this from happening? Please see the below images for better understanding.

[image]

***(Showing the mockup of the edit component as the actual data was showing in the actual edit component)***

[image]

I have clicked the edit button once and then clicked the cancel button once and this is the console log got generated.

[image]

Comment: Is your app using React's "strict mode"? If so, your answer is [here](https://medium.com/@andreasheissenberger/react-components-render-twice-any-way-to-fix-this-91cf23961625)

Comment: Each time it rerenders your action handelers are being remade in the memory, checkout useCallback or useMemo on the React docs.

Answer (score 0):

Please uase spread operators on initializing or settingup states

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({...initialState});

const handleCancel = () => {
    setEditFlag(false);
    setInputs({...initialState});
};
```